# What is the Epsilon Framework that being used by some of the Mobile templates in ThemeForest?

Tags: mobile, frameworks, themes

I need someone that can explain to me what is Epsilon Framework is all about? I have a friend that just purchased two mobile tempalates at ThemeForest site which is Clean Mobile and Glovebox theme.

So then when i studied his source code, i realize the title on the html page says "Epsilon Framework 2.0" and the script src use the something like "framework.plugins.js". It may be weird but i like the templates has been designed especially for mobile. However, when i search for this framework in google, i don't find any homepage about it and all i found only the demo of this plugin and some non-related stuff.

Therefore, can someone tells me what is this framework really is? The code looks clean and i really want to learn it if possible. If someone ever used these sort of plugins, can you tell me where can i find the docs and is it an open source?

Here's the link towards that mobile template i talked about.

[Clean Mobile](https://themeforest.net/item/cleanmobile-mobile-wordpress-theme/19727846)

[GloveBox 3D](https://themeforest.net/item/glovebox-mobile-tablet-template/9057710)

Thank you.

Comment: its machotheme right? I may be forgot to mention i did find this link too but as i mention about framework.plugin.js. I didn't find it anywhere in the directory. Plus i realize that the theme that has been used by my friend themes does not have classes been used anywhere. I can't show the code since i can't take the source code. Also, the  version still 1x whilst the theme have 2.0. Something is not right.

Comment: In addition, the docs seems incomplete. I hope someone can help me find this framework.